# (1) let ans = empty (2) for i from 1 to n do: $ans = A \cap ( ans \cup B_i )$ How to prove that $A \cap (\cup B_i) = ans$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a problem on set theory.
My problem is:

(1) let $ans_0 = empty$

(2) for i from 1 to n do: $ans_i = A \cap ( ans_{i-1} \cup B_i )$

How to prove that

$A \cap (\cup B_i) = ans_n$ ?

Comment: What do your meam by ans

Comment: ans is short for "anwser", it is used as a variable set. the set ans is initially an empty set, then it is calculated iteratively in step(2)

Comment: Add what you have done to solve this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_0, A_1,\ldots $ refer to the sequence of *ans* values, starting with $A_0 = \varnothing$, and with $A_{n+1} = (B_n\cup A_n) \cap C$.

The claim is that for any $n$, $A_{n+1} = C\cap \bigcup_{i=0}^n B_i$. The proof is by induction.

In the base case that $n=0$, we have $A_1 = (B_0 \cup A_0) \cap C = (B_0 \cup \varnothing)\cap C = B_0 \cap C$, so the statement holds.

In the inductive case, suppose $A_{n+1} = C\cap \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$ and consider $A_{n+2}$. We have that

$$\begin{align*}A_{n+2} &= (B_{n+1} \cup A_{n+1}) \cap C 
& \text{defn of }A_{n+2}\\ 
&= \left(B_{n+1} \cup \left[C \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i\right] \right)\cap C & \text{induction hypothesis}\\
&= \left[B_{n+1} \cup C\right] \cap \left[B_{n+1} \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i\right] \cap C& \text{distribution }a\cap (b\cup c)\\
&= C\cap \left[B_{n+1} \cup C\right] \cap \left[B_{n+1} \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i\right]&\text{rearrange terms}\\
&= \left[C\right] \cap \left[\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} B_i\right] & \text{absorption}\\
&= C \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} B_i\\
\end{align*}$$